# gsutil cp is unzipping my gzipped files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a bunch of already gzipped files in GCS that I'd like to download but keep compressed. When I try to download the files running command: `gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-bucket-name/path/to/dir/`, it downloads the files then immediately unzips them.

The files appear to have `Content-Encoding:gzip` in their metadata, and `gsutil cp` seems to have the default behavior that files with this encoding will automatically decompress when served.

How can I just download the files as-is without it being automatically decompressed?

Comment: Based on the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding

It looks like I need to add "Accept-Encoding: gzip" to the header.

Yet if I run the command `gsutil -h "Accept-Encoding: gzip" cp gs://my-bucket-name/path/to/dir/` it results in an "Invalid header specified" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the option `Cache-Control: no-transform` as indicated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding).

As an example:

```
gsutil -m -h "Cache-Control: no-transform" cp -r gs://YOUR-BUCKET/ .
```